# Realm - insert object at the beginning of table

Tags: kotlin, realm

I insert/update my Realm database like this:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().use {
    realmInstance -> realmInstance.executeTransaction {
        realm -> realm.insertOrUpdate(data)
    }
}
```

But this puts newly added data at the end of the table content. How can I put the data at the beginning?

---

Respone from API:

1. Latest item
2. Other items

Scenerio A: This is the first time I receive items from API. I insert them in database in the same exact order.

After a while, I've to send the latest item from my local storage. Usually this would be the `last` item in local database, but as the list is in reverse order from API, I've to send the first item (you can see order of list). Well. After some while I get a new data from API. We insert in database. From this moment, the latest item will be always the last one in database. I could avoid this mess if I just always knew, that the latest item would be the very first item. It would work for both cases.

Comment: why does it matter where it ends up?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Updated the post with exact situation.

Comment: does the table not have a timestamp or other value from which you can derive the desired order, rather than depending on the order of the list itself?

Comment: It does not. I was just wondering if there's such a possibility to make sure where to insert data, but it looks like the easiest way and possibly the best one is to add a new field in API.

Comment: There is no such thing as "order in table" in Realm, deletion moves the last item in place of the deleted item. You should have a timestamp and sort based on that.